# How to properly specify FileOpenpicker.FileTypeFilter syntax for UWP

Tags: vb.net, uwp, fileopenpicker

Is there a way to specify the filter like in OpenFileDialog, e.g.

```
openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
```

`FileOpenpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add` doesn't seem to accept the same syntax.
MSDN is a poor source of information in these regards and does not provide examples for vb.net

Comment: Can you just put it on separate lines, like in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.filetypefilter.aspx?  So FileOpenpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt") on one line, then FileOpenpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*") on the next?  I'm not sure about the labels though, and I'm unable to try it.

Comment: That's the point. If I set

               `filedialog.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt")`

               `filedialog.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv")`
The result is this http://i.imgur.com/JCRKTU7.png

Comment: The image comes up as blank for me.  The FileSavePicker example code has this... are you able to do anything similar for the FileOpenPicker?  savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt" })

Comment: FileTypeChoices method does not exist in FileOpenPicker class, and FileTypeFilter.Add only accepts one argument.

Answer (score 3):

You probably got it by now, but in any case this is the way to do it (C#):

```
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xxx");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".yyy");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
```

This will show 3 items on the list (*.xxx), (*.yyy) and "All files (*)".

Comment: Minor nitpick & a quick clarification. One, that doesn't provide the *name* of the file type, the `Text Files` in `Text Files (.txt)` from the OP. Have you stumbled over how to do that? [MSDN doesn't show it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.filetypefilter), strangely enough, so perhaps you can't? [which would stink] And the `All files` isn't from `*`, afaict, but from *the superset of all added filters*, which reduces to `*` when `*` is added. That is, if you'd left `*` off, above, you'd have `All files (*.xxx;*.yyy)` as an option.

Comment: It's been 6 years and I still have the same issues as ruffin in WinUI 3. What glorious days of Microsoft UIs.